# Cast generic property of type T up to a known inheriting type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm getting the following compiler error

> Cannot convert type 'T' to
>   'ProjectReportingHandler'

for the line

```
var projectReport = (ProjectReportingHandler)result.Report;
```

when trying to compile:

```
public abstract class ReportingHandler
{
    // Report stuff
}

public abstract class ProjectReportingHandler: ReportingHandler
{
    // Report stuff
    // Project specific report stuff
}

public class ReportInstance<T>
    where T : ReportingHandler
{
    public T Report { get; private set; }
}

public class ReportLibraryEntry<T>
        where T : ReportingHandler
{
    public ReportInstance<T> Create()
    {
        ReportInstance<T> result = new ReportInstance<T>();

        if (result.Report is ProjectReportingHandler)
        {
            var projectReport = (ProjectReportingHandler)result.Report;
            // do stuff with project reports
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to cast the linked generic type property `result.Report` to a `ProjectReportingHandler`?

I would have thought the `where T : ReportingHandler` would have ensured this was possible :(

EDIT: I seem to be getting a few responses that say my accepted answer is incorrect. It works, and I implemented it as follows:

```
public ReportInstance<T> Create()
{
    ReportInstance<T> result = new ReportInstance<T>();

    ReportingHandler report = result.Report;
    if (report is ProjectReportingHandler)
    {
        var projectReport = (ProjectReportingHandler)report;
        // do stuff with project reports
    }

    return result;
}
```

Why the down votes for an answer that worked? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "cheat" by first casting result.Report to an object, and then to a ProjectReportingHandler.

Comment: This can throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Great, thanks! Seems like this should be a built-in compiler trick though, as I can't see why preventing this with the aforementioned error is useful :s

Comment: @SLaks: Even when I have the code within the `if (result.Report is ProjectReportingHandler)` block?

Comment: It will be a little it slower, since it will cast twice.  It's faster to call `as` and check whether it's `null`.

Answer (score 4):

`where T : ReportingHandler` is not enough.
What should happen if `T` is some other type that inherits `ReportingHandler` but not `ProjectReportingHandler`?

If you're sure that `T` will always inherit from `ProjectReportingHandler`, you can change the constraint to `where T : ProjectReportingHandler`.

If you really want to do it the way you're doing it now, you should first cast to `ReportingHandler`, like this:

```
var projectReport = ((ReportingHandler)result.Report) as ProjectReportingHandler;
```

If `T` does not inherit `ProjectReportingHandler`, `projectReport` will be `null`.

Comment: But I have the line `if (result.Report is ProjectReportingHandler)` which will be the containing condition... I don't see why it wouldn't always be a `ProjectReportingHandler` if I check first?

Comment: It will be a little it slower, since it will cast twice.  It's faster to call `as` and check whether it's `null`.

Comment: I see your point, but the speed improvement is a minor difference :) Besides, are you sure the IL is that much different? Would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 3):

T : ReporingHandler does not guarantee that that the conversion is possible. Just because a ProjectReportingHandler is a ReportingHandler doesn't mean the opposite is true.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `as`:

```
        ReportInstance<T> result = new ReportInstance<T>();
        var projectReport = result.Report as ProjectReportingHandler;
        if (projectReport != null)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

Comment: Actually this workaround is better than the accepted answer because "cheatcasting" does 2 casts, while this `as` uses 1 cast.