# C# compiler is afraid from casting when reference conversion?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0

Ive seen this code :

```
StringBuilder Foo<T> (T arg)
{
 if (arg is StringBuilder)
 return (StringBuilder) arg; // Will not compile
 ...
}
```

however :

```
StringBuilder Foo<T> (T arg)
{
 StringBuilder sb = arg as StringBuilder;
 if (sb != null) return sb;
 ...
}
```

**will** compile.

why is that ? what the compiler is afraid of ?

p.s. ive seen another solution which :

```
(StringBuilder) (object) arg
```

Comment: The `(T)(object)` is generally fast enough. I use that normally.

Comment: @leppie and hows that answering my questions ? :)

Comment: You are returning a specific type that could still fail the cast on return.

Comment: what's the use of that code? I think generics are there to avoid castings...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Cast vs as operator revisited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099617/c-cast-vs-as-operator-revisited)

Comment: @vulkanino reference conversion.  this code is from a book.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It is not, hence a comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, cause there is no guranteed conversion between type `T` and `StringBuilder`.
Specifying it like `arg as StringBuilder`, if coversion fails, it will return a `null` and *not* exception, like in previouse case. `Null` is a valid case, in this function, like a returning type.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler must know that a cast will work at compile time. You can actually implement explicit cast operators on your own classes. However, the conversion (`as`) includes a runtime check and returns null if the conversion fails.

As the compiler does not know anything about `T`, it won't compile. The `if` does not change that fact, as it just makes sure it would work at runtime. But the compiler doesn't analyse runtime behaviour.